# mdc-select renders on top of everything

Tags: css, mdc-components

I am working on a project were we are using mdc-select for dropdowns and now we have a bug that makes the selectboxes render on top of everything. Which is quite problematic because we need to have a popup render on top of it.

I suspected it might be due to z-index but the z-index of the popup is much higher then the z-index of the selectbox. I tried disabling the z-index of the selectbox in dev tools as well and it makes no difference. What else can there be affecting the layers?

Problem dissapears when removing mdc styling.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a z-index after all that had to be overridden in the popup.